# How can classic home page's file name be home.aspx but the title is different?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, title

I renamed the home page `.aspx` file for a classic site collection from `home.aspx` to `home_classic.aspx`.

By doing this, the site title on the home page itself is not maintained. Upon initial creation it said this:

[image]

However, upon renaming the `.aspx` file what used to be `SER AM BSS` is not exactly the same as the file name, i.e. `home_classic`.

How can I maintain the site title whilst renaming the `.aspx` file?

EDIT:

Here's what the result is when I Rename-PnPFile 'home.aspx' to 'home_classic.aspx':

[image]

It all of a sudden takes the file name on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Site title (name) and Name of the home page for site are two different things. Site title will not be changed if you rename the home page for that site.

Follow below steps to change site name:

1. Go to your site and click on Settings (Gear icon)
2. Click on **Site Information**
3. Enter desired site name in the text box of **Site name**
4. Click **Save**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, all true what you say but why when I rename the .aspx file, e.g. via Rename-PnPFile to 'Home_classic' the home page carries the .aspx file's name below the site title which has not changed? Please see my edited intitial post, where I added another screenshot.

I want either what's now 'Home_classic' not to be there at all or be named as previously, like the site title prior to renaming the .aspx file itself.

Comment: I test it and update the result in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the homepage name will only affect the display name in the address bar:

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
I run the below pnp powershell to rename the home page of current site collection in site pages library, only the address bar URL has been changed.

```
Rename-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl /sites/site collection name/SitePages/HomeW.aspx -TargetFileName HelloTest.aspx -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists
```

[image]

Please create a new site collection and test again.